# Sort by time (epoch) mysql

Tags: python, mysql, discord

i get time (epoch) from mysql bd

```
"SELECT * FROM `tables` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 20")
```

format my tables:

### id    | time

```
  01    | 1664898681
  02    | 1664898561
  03    | 1664898501
```

in discord epoch time sort now
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xDY9.png)

---

```
  01    | in 10 minutes
  02    | in 9 minutes
  03    | in 8 minutes
  04    | 23 minutes ago
```

in the table the data is unix time(epoch) , I need to sort the time in the format closest to the current time

---

```
  01    | in 8 minutes
  02    | in 9 minutes
  03    | in 10 minutes
  04    | 23 minutes ago
```

Comment: How are you trying to sort it? The way you've described increases in time, and then suddenly goes to 23 minutes ago, which is not a consistent sorting method, unless you simply mean you wish to sort by number of minutes, regardless of chronological direction?

Comment: @Basil
in the table the data is unix time(epoch) , I need to sort the time in the format closest to the current time

Comment: What does "Sort closest to the current time" mean? `ORDER BY yourdatetimecolumn DESC`? I also don't fully understand your data in this column. You show `1664898681` as sample data but then also `in 10 minutes`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

To sort your data by the closest time to now, you will need to:

- First, convert it to a MySQL date using `FROM_UNIXTIME`, assuming that it is not already in this format, and it just a number representing the epoch time.
- Calculate the **absolute** difference between the time now and the time listed
- Sort by this value

---

However, you want to sort so that *future* events show before past ones, no matter how soon the past ones are.

Therefore, we need to order by whether they are in the future/past first, before we order by distance from now.

To do this, we:

- Once again, convert using `FROM_UNIXTIME`.
- Calculate the difference between now and the time.
- Take the `SIGN` of this, to get `1` for dates in the future, and `-1` for those in the past.
- Sort by the sign descending, to get future dates first.

Since we want to sort by this first, we must put it first in the query:

```sql
[..] ORDER BY SIGN(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`) - NOW()) DESC, ABS(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`) - NOW()) ASC
```

Comment: thx, but is it possible to make it so that it first displays records of the future tense, and only then the past

now the first record is displayed elapsed in time

Comment: @Bonjour Sorry, I don't get what you mean? How do you want to sort it differently?

Comment: @Bonjour I just checked back on this and figured out what you meant - It's a bit late, but I hope my edited answer answers your question, and you can mark it as accepted :)